# Error when getting a UWP package info from a Winform App?

Tags: c#, uwp, desktop-bridge

Using a `WinForm` App, I'm trying to mimic this [sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Package) from Microsoft's Github site that shows how to get package info by using the Windows Runtime packaging API.

I'm getting following error at line: `Package package = Package.Current;`, of the code below, when trying to get a UWP package info from a **WinForm app**:

> > The type or namespace name 'Package' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

**Question**: Although the error is a famous C# error that has many online posts/solutions, but here the context is different. Compiler seems to be complaining that I'm missing required assembly for [Package class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.ApplicationModel.Package). But I do have `using Windows.ApplicationModel;` using statement in my code below. So what may be a possible cause of the error; i.e. what I may be missing here?

**NOTE**: To ensure the inclusion of the required assemblies, I did install this [UWPDesktop](https://www.nuget.org/packages/UwpDesktop) NuGet package in WinForm Project on `VS2017-ver 15.9.5` on `Windows 10 Pro - Ver 8109`:

**WinForm App**: Relevant code that `throws error` at line: `Package package = Package.Current;`

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Windows.ApplicationModel; //I added from here
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Background;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.Storage;
using Windows.Storage.Search;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.Management.Deployment;

namespace WinForms_to_UWP
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Package package = Package.Current;
            PackageId packageId = package.Id;

            Console.WriteLine(packageId.FullName);
        }
    }
}
```

**From the GitHub's UWP Sample project**: The relevant Code from [scenario1_identity.xaml.cs](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/Package/cs/scenario1_identity.xaml.cs) that WORKS fine:

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using SDKTemplate;
using System;
using Windows.ApplicationModel;

namespace SDKTemplate
{
void GetPackage_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Package package = Package.Current;
    PackageId packageId = package.Id;

    String output = String.Format("Name: \"{0}\"\n" + packageId.FullName);

    OutputTextBlock.Text = output;
}
```

**UPDATE**:

Also worth noticing that when adding `Using Windows.....` statements on the top, the `VS intellisense` recognized only `Window.Foundation` and `Window.UI.` statements. For other `Using Windows.....` statements I had to hardcode - for example, `Windows.ApplicationModel;`. However `VS2017` did not complain when I hard coded them. Moreover, all `Using` statements starting with `Windows.` are grayed out as shown in image below. Not sure if it has anything to do with the error:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Nuget package you are referencing is outdated I am afraid and may not be maintained anymore.

But the problem is easy to fix. Just add a reference to the windows.winmd file of the SDK version you are targeting. See this screenshot:

[image]

Comment: When, from `VS2017` I tried to reference from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\10.0.17763.0` I saw only `Façade` folder but not `Windows.winmd` file you are referencing. However, in Windows Explorer, I can see that file in the above mentioned path. How do I force VS2017 to show me that file when using `Project-->Add Reference>…..` menu? Also, my system is x64 and Program Files folder for x64 does not have Windows Kits folder - I'm not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: You need to change the file extension filter to "All Files *.*", like I am showing in the screenshot. Then you will see the windows.winmd file. I know, it's not very obvious  ...

Comment: Sorry, I should have paid attention to your red squares you clearly showed. Now, I can add your suggested reference. But after running `Clean   solution` and then `Rebuild Solution` I'm still getting exact same error. I've added an **UPDATE** section - just in case.

Comment: It works for me. Here is my test project, can you share yours?
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AovTwKUMywTNsOk74mT31BIZjpXwhw

Comment: At home I created same test `WinForm` project with almost same environment and it worked. The only difference - that I can think of - from Work and Home environment is that at work I was using`.NET Framework 4.7.2` whereas; at Home I'm using `4.6.2`. But, I doubt if that would have made any difference for my test example. Although, I'm getting a different error (similar to this [one](https://github.com/Microsoft/DesktopBridgeToUWP-Samples/issues/60)). But that require a different post. You answered what was asked. Please let me know if you would still like me to share project.

Comment: No need to share your project. Please mark this one as answered. Thx!